# rake db:migrate does nothing, even on reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-migrations

Here is a very strange issue I have on my new computer setup (otherwise, it's working on my other setups).

I'm running : `rake db:migrate`
No errors, but it does nothing...

`rake db:migrate:status` show me the list of pendings migrations (marked as "down"), the ones that I effectively have in my bd/migrate folder.

Even if I run those commands or removing files in db/* manually, `db:migrate` is still useless.
`rake db:drop:all`
`rake db:create`
`rake db:migrate`

I have tried also `db:reset`, `db:rollback STEP=1000`.

If I specify a VERSION number (one from the list given by db:migrate:status) as:
`rake db:migrate VERSION=20150106184930`

I've got the following error:
`No migration with version number 20150106184930`

I have also generated a new migration with:
`rails generate migration TestMigration`
And again, `db:migrate` completely ignor it.

My current setup is: windows7, rails 4.2.0, rake 10.3.2.

Thanks for any help, clues...

Comment: what is the content of your `schema_migrations` table?  What happens when you run `rake db:rollback`?

Comment: The content of schema.rb is quite blank.
It only shows the main structure, waiting for the pending migrations.   
  

`ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do  
end`
  
Also my localhost:3000 claims about pendings migrations.

rake db:rollback STEP=1000 changes nothing...

Comment: No, not your `schema.rb` file, your `schema_migrations` table in your database.  It certainly might not be there, but if it is, does it have any content?  It wouldn't be in your `schema.rb`, it's just rails plumbing.

Comment: Ok, I never heard about this table before. Is there a way I can access this schema_migration table from rails console?

Comment: There are ways to get that from Rails, but honestly it's easier if you just do it using a database client (pgAdmin or similar)

Comment: Ok I looked into the database (sqlite3). There is a table schema_migrations with only one entry. `rowid=1` and `version=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of deep debugging in rake, reinstalled all my complete setup, I finally figured out that the problem was comming from the "non so special" characters `[` or `]` somewere in my project path!!

DAMN RAILS!

Due to readability, all my project's folders start with "[NAME-OF-PROJECT]xxxx/"... then in this particular rails project comes a subfolder for the rails app.

No error, nothing that point you out that the path name could be the issue. I'm quite sur that "[" and "]" are not forbidden character (even on linux) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words
And why "[" or "]" makes `rake db:migrate` failing and not `rake db:migrate:status`???

For me it clearly shows some weakness in rails architecture. I should probably do a bug report for that... can someone point me some report mailing list or whatever?

I hope that my misadventure will save hours for others.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new rails setup, you may not have gems on your system, but only in your app. Try prepending `bundle exec` to your `rake` commands.

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but already tried. It changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try run `gem update` and try `rake db:migrate` again.

Comment: Gem update have upgraded rake from 10.3.2 to 10.4.2. that do not wan't to works because it require ruby >=2.0.0. I'm running with 1.9.3. If I specify 'bundle exec' to rake execution to use 10.3.2, it's still doing nothing.

Comment: @Flavien Instead of wasting your time going into this loop, why not do a fresh installation again. It might solves your problem.